# MacOSX Find Media Files

Tags: macos, finder

I need a way to "disinfect/de-porn" a Mac system...Its not mine of course...This is for a "friend!"

I'm looking for an app that will search out and put into a single finder window all video files. I can certainly use find command but I don't know all the various media types, extensions or even files without extensions.

There must be an app that is aware of all the various media types and can search a drive(s) for such files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finder does this itself. Have you tried simply searching on filetype video and then moving these to a folder?

Comment: Sure, the issue I don't know all the media types. Plus mac files don't need an extension.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Press option-command-space to open a Spotlight window and set the kind to movies or images:

[image]

Or use `mdfind`:

```
mdfind kMDItemContentTypeTree=public.movie -onlyin ~/ | grep -v ~/Library
```